# Get group range of Excel list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of values which belong to several groups.
Based on the groups I want to calculate the rank and the quantile of every value within its group.

My approach was getting the range of every group using a formula, but I am already stuck with that one.

I hope someone has an idea.

[image]

Comment: Is your data always going to be ordered this nicely?

Comment: yes, i get this data with an sql statement on an excel-sheet (except quantile and rank)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `MATCH()` and `OFFSET()`.
In `E2` put:

```
=RANK.EQ(C2,
         OFFSET($C$2,
                MATCH(A2, $A$2:$A$14, 0) - 1,
                0,
                COUNTIF($A$2:$A$14, A2)))
```

What this does is calculate the rank by:

1. Finding the first row of the current group with `MATCH()`
2. Using that - 1 as the offset from the first row of data `$C$2`
3. Calculate the number of rows by counting the number of occurrences of the group with `COUNTIF()`
4. Finally get the rank of that range

Applying this for the quantile you can just divide that by `COUNTIF($A$2:$A$14, A2)`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm almost at the solution:
do you have an idea to transform the calculated quantil value into the corresponding number (1, 2, 3 or 4)?

Comment: To get the qua**r**tiles try `CEILING(<quantile>*4,1)`